# Dropdown with 2 information in each row (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a dropdown box with something like:

```
Madrid (10)
Amsterdam (20)
Paris (5)
New York (14)
```

So the name of the Ciy + a point

I am using this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT city_name, city_point FROM ".CITIES_TABLE.""; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
$city_name = array("---"); 
while ($city_row = $site_db->fetch_array($result)) {
      $city_name[] = current($city_row); 
      $additional_combo_fields['combo_city'] = array($lang['combo_city'], 
                                                     "dropdown", 
                                                      0,
                                                      $city_name,
                                                      0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Now I am getting, of course, only the name of the cities, but I don't how to get also the points.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

```
$city_name = $city_row[0]; // or $city_row['city_name']
$city_point = $city_row[1]; // or $city_row['city_point']
```

See code below:

```
$sql = "SELECT city_name, city_point FROM ".CITIES_TABLE.""; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
$city_name = array("---"); 
while ($city_row = $site_db->fetch_array($result)) {

      $additional_combo_fields['combo_city'] = array($lang['combo_city'], 
                                                     "dropdown", 
                                                      0,
                                                      $city_row[0].' ('.$city_row[1].')',
                                                      0, 0, 0, 0);

}
```

Comment: U should eloborate this answer.. It's way to cryptic at this point

Comment: Elaborated it, better?